# Concurrent requests limited to 10 in .Net MVC / Web Api

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I'm doing some scalability testing, particularly when it comes to the number of connections / requests that can be executed concurrently for a particular Web API call.

I created an API function which performs a `Thread.Sleep(10000)` (Sleep for 10 seconds)

I'm making a call to the API using JMeter (a benchmarking platform http://jmeter.apache.org/) to execute 50 requests all at once on different threads.

- My first 10 threads to reach the website are returned 10 seconds later.
- Followed by 10 more threads 10 more seconds later (20 returned now)
- Followed by 10 more threads 10 more seconds later (30 returned now)
- Etc. until all 50 have returned.

Clearly, the 11th attempt to call the API is blocked until a thread / connection, etc. is freed up (or something similar).

I've confirmed that 10 is the magic number in my scenario because I changed my sleep time to **5000ms** and I'm able to process **10** threads in **5** seconds, followed by another **10** threads in the next **5** seconds.

Why is this happening? What is imposing this limit I'm seeing here?

*P.S. I've tried this with a fresh MVC project as well, same results with all brand new setup.*

Comment: [system.web applicationPool element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842(v=vs.110).aspx) may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS on Windows 8.1 Pro (Or Windows 7 Ultimate) has a limit of 10 simultaneous requests (3 for Windows 8.1 Basic).

Generally, if you try to run production workload, you should use Windows Server which doesn't have this limitation.

See [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit) for more details about the limitation.